# Integrable and order

Tags: integration, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $f \in C((0,1])$ be a non-negative real-valued function, and

$$\int^1_0 f(x)dx < \infty$$

then does the following hold? $$\lim_{x \to 0} xf(x) =0$$

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: A good way to figure this out is to think about the definition of the definite integral in terms of limits. More precisely what is each term of a Riemann sum?

Comment: Advice: look for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for a counterexample:

- if the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} x f(x)$ exists then it must be $0$ otherwise the improper integral would diverge, so the limit must not exist for a counterexample;
- $f(x)$ cannot be monotonic, otherwise the conclusion would hold per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113036/fx-is-positive-continuous-monotone-and-integrable-in-0-1-is-lim-x-r);
- a sequence of spikes or square pulses can become arbitrarily large near $0$ and still keep the integral converging, provided they also become narrow enough.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   An explicit counterexample can be built as a "sawtooth" function with increasingly high and more narrow "teeth" towards 0. The "teeth" would need to be tall enough so that they get comparable to $\frac{1}{x}$, and narrow enough so that the improper integral still converges.

For an example, the rightmost $5$ "teeth" of such a function could be:

[image]

The above uses:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2^n \Lambda\left(2^{2n}\left(x - \frac{1}{2^n}\right)\right) & \quad x \in \left(\frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^{2n}}, \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right) \;\;\text{for some}\;\;n \in \mathbb{N} \text{,}\;n \ge 2  \\
0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

where $\Lambda$ is the [triangular function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleFunction.html):

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda(x) = \max(1-|x|,0) =
\begin{cases}
1 - |x| & \quad \quad |x| \le 1 \\
0 & \quad \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

It can be shown that the $n^{th}$ triangular "tooth":

- has an area of $\frac{1}{2^n}$, so the improper integral converges;
- attains a maximum of $2^n$at $x_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$, so $x_n f(x_n) = 1$ for $\forall n \ge 2$ therefore $\lim_{x \to 0} x f(x)$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Very good.